# How to migrate from MiaCMS to Joomla 1.5?

Tags: content-management-system, joomla, migration, joomla1.5

How do I convert from MiaCMS to Joomla? They both have a common ancestry in Mambo CMS (RIP). Now that MiaCMS is going the same way I need to move to something else and Joomla seems to be the best choice. There should be enough commonality to port over. And MiaCMS has a porting instructions from Mambo that could possibly be used to create a conversion script. I want to go directly to Joomla 1.5 if that is possible, although porting to Joomla 1.x and then upgrading would be an option. I tried to install Migrator (as described in the [Joomla 1.0 to 1.5 migration guide](http://docs.joomla.org/Migrating_from_1.0.x_to_1.5_Stable)) in MiaCMS but that didn't seem to work.

Comment: I really wanted to add a MiaCMS tag here too, but I couldn't create a new tag. Someone with more reps, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing was simply exporting the three tables mia_sections, mia_categories and mia_content as sql from my MiaCMS database. Then I replaced all references to mia_ with jos_. Then I could simply do a database import of the three sql-backup files into a pristine Joomla 1.5 installation. And Voila! all essential data converted.

Of course I had to re-populate and structure the website layout with appropriate modules but that was a fairly simple job compared to copying all the content by hand.

Template conversion turned out to be a hassle so I just started afresh from a properly designed Joomla 1.5 template and tweaked it to my liking.